# Convert a file to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, dictionary

I have a text file like this:

```
line1 =       mainline3
line2 = subline  9
line3 = mainline1
line4 =    mainline 9
line5 =     mainline     7
line6 = subline      3
```

I wish to read this file to a dictionary such that the lines containing 'mainline' are the key and the lines with 'subline' the value of the previous mainline

Example:

```
d = {3: 9, 1: '', 9: '', 7: 3}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do. You first read the file, then you loop per line and then you capture the data as needed. The important part is to make sure the loop doesn't add a key for each line, it only adds a key to the dict after a subline.

This code assumes that txt file integrity is correct with the order. I used this txt file for my tests:

```
mainline1
subline  9
mainline2
subline 8
mainline     3
subline      3
mainline4
mainline5
subline 9
mainline     6
subline      3
```

Make sure that it's 1 mainline and 1 subline alternatively. It won't work if that order is different because it stors the last key found and then it adds it to the dict when it founds a new subline. If you have for example `main main sub`, the first main would be ignored as the 2nd one would replace it before it got a chance to be added.

**Code:**

```
with open("myfile.txt", 'r') as f: # Open file
    file_content = f.read() # Read file
my_dict = {} # Create empty dict to store the data

list_of_lines = file_content.split("\n") # Split the files into a list of lines.
for index, line in enumerate(list_of_lines):
    add_to_dict = False
    if "mainline" in line:
        key = line.replace("mainline", "").strip() # Retrieve the value without the word mainline
        if ("mainline" in list_of_lines[index+1] # If next line is also a mainline 
            or index == len(list_of_lines): # or it's the last line in the file
            my_dict[key] = "" # Add the key with an empty value
    elif "subline" in line:
        value = line.replace("subline", "").strip() # Retrieve the value without the word subline
        add_to_dict = True
    if add_to_dict: # Only add the key and its value after a subline.
        my_dict[key] = value
print(my_dict) # See the result.

>>> {'4': '', '6': '3', '3': '3', '1': '9', '5': '9', '2': '8'}
```

Comment: What if i have mainlines without sublines? Could I assign them nothing as value?

Comment: Yup, I updated the code. We can use enumerate to save the index of each line. Then we can check if the index+1 (the next item) is also a mainline. If it's just add that to the dict with an empty value.

Comment: Also, you seem a new member to Stack Overflow. Welcome aboard! Remember that if an answer works for you, you can accept it as valid with the controls at the left side of the answer ^^

Comment: I noticed that if the last line contains "mainline" the code doesn't add it to the dictionary

Comment: Indeed, because the code checks if the next line is also a main before adding an empty valie, but if it's the last one there is no more lines to check so it never adds that empty value. The updated code "should" work.